# How do I call a C Function from a Jython script?

Tags: java, python, compilation, jython

I am creating a GUI using Jython. I want to program my logic in C. How could I can call a C Function from my Python Code. Sorry if this a newbie question, but I have never worked with linking files except Sparc Assembly from C.

Comment: It's not a dup, because he's using Jython, not CPython.

Answer (score 4):

Jython cannot use `ctypes`, or C extension modules (whether built manually, or with Cython, or otherwise).

The way to do this is the same way as in Java: Through a JNI bridge.

First, you write a C++ wrapper that talks to the so, and uses functions from `<jni.h>` to implement functions like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL _PACKAGE(bar)(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jint i) {
    if (bar(i)) {
        throwPyFromErrno(env, OSError);
    }
}
```

Next, in Java, you define a `public` class full of Java wrappers around those C++ wrappers, like this:

```
public class foo implements InitModule {
    public final static native void bar(int i);
}
```

Finally, in Jython, you can just import the class (which acts like a Python module) from its Java module and use it like any other module:

```
try:
    foo.bar(3)
except OSError as e:
    print "Failed:", e
```

---

Most of this is standard JNI, but you also have to know things like how to create Jython objects. Ideally, you'll use wrappers for that, so you can just write `makePyInteger(env, value)` or `throwPyFromErrno(env, exctype)` instead of doing all the `FindClass`, `GetStaticMethodID`, etc. stuff manually.

I don't have any tutorials to recommend. But see [jnios](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnios/) for a nice-sized example. The O'Reilly book's [Chapter 25. Extending and Embedding Jython](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/other/python/0596001886_pythonian-chp-25.html) seems like it might be a decent primer (although I haven't read it). You'll probably want to read a tutorial on using JNI for Java before trying to tackle Jython.

Answer (score 0):

A different way to solve this problem is to break your single program into two pieces.

The GUI program runs in Jython. When it needs to call the C code, it does that by running a worker program.

The worker program runs in CPython or PyPy, so it can use any of the usual techniques for talking to C libraries: [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), [`cffi`](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.6/), [a custom C extension module](http://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) (maybe using [Cython](http://www.cython.org), [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/index.html), [SWIG](http://www.swig.org), [SIP](http://riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/intro), …), [Weave](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/weave.html), etc.

---

For a simple case, where you just need to call one function, pass it a few strings, and get back a string, it's as trivial as this:

```
import subprocess

def my_function(*args):
    return subprocess.check_output(['python', 
                                    '/path/to/worker/script.py'] + args)
```

(Note that there are a few bugs with `subprocess` in older versions of Jython, especially on OS X and Windows. If you run into a problem, 2.5.4 and 2.7.0, which are currently in RC and beta stages, respectively, have probably fixed it.)

---

If you need to make lots of calls one at a time throughout the life of your program, you'll probably want to keep the worker script running in the background, and use some form of RPC to talk to it. [This blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-split-your-program-in-two.html) shows how to do it using the `bjsonrpc` library.